# Application is crashing when future date is set in windows phone using parse push notification

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to follow your quickstart on push notifications on windows phone 8 and it doesn't seem to be functional.

https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart_push#wp/existing

await ParsePush.SubscribeAsync("");

results and an unhandled exception in both the emulator and on a physical devices.

{Parse.ParseException: Invalid response from server ---> System.ArgumentException: Input JSON was invalid. at Parse.Internal.Json.Parse(String input) at Parse.ParseClient.DeserializeJsonString(String jsonData) at Parse.ParseClient.<>cDisplayClassb.ba(Task1 t) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Parse.ParseClient.<>c__DisplayClassb.b__a(Task1 t) at Parse.Internal.InternalExtensions.<>cDisplayClass12.b__0(Task t) at Parse.Internal.InternalExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass71.b6(Task t) at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromTask1.InnerInvoke() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at Parse.Internal.InternalExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass71.b6(Task t) at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromTask`1.InnerInvoke() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() at Parse.ParseInstallation.d4.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() at ObjectivePixel.BringCast.Cloud.CloudPlugin.d14.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() at ObjectivePixel.BringCast.Silverlight.App.d2.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.b__0(Object state)}